# Группы в регулярных выражениях

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Имеется текст вида :
Тип вопроса:2
Вопрос:авпавпвапавп
Кол-во вариантов:4
Ответ:333
Ответ:авпавп
Ответ:авпавп
Ответ:вапвапавп
Правильный ответ:1

Написал такое регулярное выражение: Тип вопроса:2(?:\n|\r|\r\n)Вопрос:(.+)(?:\n|\r|\r\n)Кол-во вариантов:(.+)(?:\n|\r|\r\n)(?:Ответ:(.+)(?:\n|\r|\r\n)){2,}Правильный ответ:(.+)
Работает: [image: Работа]

Но проблема в том, что именно в ответах в группу записывает только последний ответ:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А мне нужно все ответы.

Comment: Без указания языка программирования помочь вам никто не сможет. Вопрос неясен.

Answer (score 0):

Пример на **PHP**

```
<?php

$string = 'Тип вопроса:2 Вопрос:авпавпвапавп Кол-во вариантов:4 Ответ:333 Ответ:авпавп Ответ:авпавп Ответ:вапвапавп Правильный ответ:1';
preg_match_all('/ответ\:([\w]+)/ui', $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Результат:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "Ответ:333"
    [1]=>
    string(23) "Ответ:авпавп"
    [2]=>
    string(23) "Ответ:авпавп"
    [3]=>
    string(29) "Ответ:вапвапавп"
    [4]=>
    string(12) "ответ:1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "333"
    [1]=>
    string(12) "авпавп"
    [2]=>
    string(12) "авпавп"
    [3]=>
    string(18) "вапвапавп"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```